# Перегрузка конструктора. Ошибка multiple definition of `Tile::Tile()' и других реализаций

Tags: c++

Что не так с реализацией, почему пишет "множественное определение" всех методов за классом? Пишу в QtCreator.

```
class Tile {
public:
    // Constructor
    Tile();
    Tile(char c, char r);

    char getCol() const;
    char getRow() const;
    bool valid() const;

private:
    char col_, row_;
};

Tile::Tile()
    : col_(0), row_(0) { }

Tile::Tile(char c, char r)
    : col_(c), row_(r) { }

char Tile::getCol() const{
    return col_;
}

char Tile::getRow() const{
    return row_;
}

bool Tile::valid() const{
    return col_;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавил inline перед методами за классом и все заработало

Comment: вернул реализации конструктора обратно в тело класса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверняка вы все это поместили в заголовочном файле, который включается во многие файлы проекта...

В заголовочном файле должны находиться только объявления. Реализация может там находиться, только если она - inline, т.е. если тела функций находятся в самом объявлении класса (или объявлены вне него как `inline`).

Иначе нарушается ODR - правило одного определения...

Судите сами - при компиляции, скажем, всего двух .cpp-файлов с таким заголовочным файлом *в каждом* будет код всех функций вашего класса. С одинаковыми именами. И что делать линковщику - какой из них оставить в выполнимой программе? Какой выбросить?

Вот он, бедный, и жалуется на жизнь...